# Mi código de C# no se ve como debería ,¿falta instalar .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, unity

Estoy aprendiendo a programar con C# en Unity, veo el código de la documentación y noto que las clases no tienen el mismo color que las mías y Visual Studio Code no me recomienda métodos o funciones como suele hacer con los lenguajes de programación.

Se que se necesitan unos programas para que el código funcione correctamente pero no sé cuales son o si ya no hace falta hoy en día. Les dejo una imágen de los programas .NET que actualmente tengo.

[image: Estos son los componentes .Net que actualmente tengo]

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generalmente este problema tiene una de las siguientes soluciones.

1. Asegúrese de que el editor de código esta establecido en relación a Unity como misma herramienta de edicion de texto. A continuación como realizarlo.

Diríjase a **Edit** > **Preferences** > **External Tools** > **External Editor Script** [Aqui selecciona su editor de código o en caso de no aparecer podrá buscarlo seleccionando la opción **Browse...**]

2. Verifique que su editor de código sea compatible (En caso de no serlo, es recomendable emplear otro) con las extensiones y agregados para Unity como lo son el **Unity Tools** y **OmniSharp**. A continuación como realizar la instalación de **Unity Tools** para Visual Studio.

Abra la aplicación **Visual Studio Installer**.
Diríjase a la versión de **Visual Studio** que usted desea emplear y seleccione **Modificar** (En caso de ya tener el mismo instalado).
Diríjase al apartado de **Juegos** y marque como valida la casilla **Desarrollo de juego con Unity**. Tras estas acciones usted tendrá que instalar los nuevos agregados, suponiendo que el mismo editor sigue estando como editor de código para **Unity** debería funcionar correctamente, caso contrario le recomiendo instale **.NET 4.8** y reinicie el equipo.

Suerte en tu proyecto y en tu aprendizaje de la herramienta. Que tenga buen día.